# how fetch value from SAPGuitable in to UFT/QTP using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Material=SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Create ZOR Order: Overview").SAPGuiTable("All items").GetCellData( 1,"Material")  ...here in GetCellData my column name is changing  if i want to fetch data from row no. 1 and coloumn no. 3 then how?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
GetCellData( 1,3)....
```

that could help...it will fetch the data whatever the column name